# Generate random floats in a set of discontinuous ranges

Tags: python-2.7, random, floating-point

I am looking to generate random floats to populate a virtual reality world with objects, using the floats to define the locations of the objects. Right now it is easy to uniformly fill a "box" with objects using random.uniform call.

```
import random

#generate random floating coordinates
for z in range(1000):
    x = random.uniform(-1,1)
    y = random.uniform(-1,1)
    z = random.uniform(-1,1)
    #shape = vizshape.addSphere() commented out because this is an uncommon module for VR but I wanted to show how floats are being used
    #shape.setPosition([x,y,z])
```

What I would like to do is pass in arguments to random.uniform() that specify more than 1 range to generate floats in, something like:

```
x = random.uniform([-1,1],[2,3])
```

Of course this will cause errors but I am looking for a way to get floats in multiple, size-varying, discontinuous ranges. I'd like to do it without writing another check to see if the generated floats are within my desired ranges and then deciding to keep or throw away. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea would be to first peek a range at random and then a float inside the selected range. The problem, however, is that for this to be uniform across all ranges, their length should be taken into account. Otherwise, shorter ranges would get, in the long run, the same number of samples than longer ones, which is not a uniform behavior.

In order to address this problem we can map all ranges to, say, the interval `[0,1]` in such a way that relative lengths are preserved. Here is how:

1. Sort the ranges in ascending order and get `[a1, b1]`, ..., `[an, bn]`
2. Let `di = bi - ai` be the length of the `i`-th range
3. Let `L` be the sum of all `di`
4. Map `a1` to `0` and `b1` to `d1/L`.
5. For all `i >= 2` map `ai` to the mapping of `b_{i-1}` and `bi` to that value plus `di/L`.
6. For all `i >= 1` let `xi` be the mapping of `ai`.

Now take a random number `s` uniformly sampled in `[0,1]` and proceed as follows

1. Let `i0` be the last index `i` such that `xi <= s`.
2. Use the inverse of the `i0`-th mapping to get the answer. In other words, answer with

   f = a_{i0} + (s-xi) * L / di

   This number `f` is in the `i0`-th interval and has been chosen uniformly at random.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but it can be easily generalized to multiple discontinuous ranges:

```
import random

def getRandoms(n, ranges):
    answer = []
    for _ in xrange(n):
        low,high = random.choice(ranges)
        answer.append(random.uniform(low, high))

    return answer
```

Comment: If the ranges are of unequal lengths, this will cause the sampling to be non-uniform across the available ranges.